# Prevent Proguard obfuscating child classes with annotation

Tags: annotations, gson, proguard

I have some class with Gson annotations that I need to keep from obfuscation via ProGuard. This bit of code works

```
public abstract class FacebookIdentifier {
    @Expose public String id;
    @Expose public String name;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.* <fields>;
}
```

Now I have some classes that extend such classes with no extra field. Example:

```
class FacebookApplication extends FacebookIdentifier {}
```

Such a class is obfuscated even though its parent has some annotations that prevent it from being obfuscated. Is there a way to have this class not being obfuscated ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to specify the extension explicitly:

```
-keep class com.example.FacebookApplication
```

However, for JSON, the class names probably don't matter; only the field names. Preserving the fields should be sufficient:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.* <fields>;
}
```

This is assuming that all serialized fields are annotated, which is not strictly required for GSON.

Comment: Having to define each class explicitely is what I'm trying to avoid. This is not very refactoring safe. So not good to maintain.

The `-keepclassmembers` doesn't work better than `-keepclasseswithmembers`, it doesn't take inherited classes in account.